# How to solve Junit.jar library missing error in eclipse for openbravo

Tags: eclipse, junit, openbravo

Imported openbravo in eclipse.

Everything is working fine except showing one error on main openbravo project, it shows missing required library junit.jar

[image]

[image]

I tried by deleting jar file and adding downloaded jar file but it gave lot of errors.

Why it happened ?

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Execute "ant setup" before running "install.source" and import into Eclipse.
Ant setup process will add "org.eclipse.wst.common.component" under .settings folder,.classpath and it will solve 99% of issues during import.

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Openbravo_Setup

Comment: Ok, i'll execute ant setup from terminal before running install.source(but i'm using openbravo from 3 month i've never ran install.source ).Importing means what ? drag and drop build.xml in eclipse or importing whole openbravo project in eclipse ?

Comment: Checked :-                                                                              openbravo@Z3d:~$ vim.tiny workspace/obdev/.settings/org.eclipse.
org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.common.component
org.eclipse.wst.common.component.template
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
openbravo@Z3d:~$ vim.tiny workspace/obdev/.settings/org.eclipse.